# How to assign SuperUser (aka: admin/root) privileges to a normal user in Mumble?

Tags: mumble

I am trying to configure my first Mumble server and I would like to assign the privileges of default *SuperUser* account to another user. I read the documentation but I didn't really understand how to do it?

Can you explain me, step-by-step, how to do it?

---

**Note:** "SuperUser" is the name [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net/FAQ/English#Where_is_the_administrator_account.3F) gives to the adminsitrator/root account.  This isn't in reference to SuperUser.com.

> The topmost user in the Mumble hierarchy is the useraccount "SuperUser", which bypasses all permission checks and is always allowed to do anything.